The coefficients of the Jack polynomials are polynomials in the Jack parameter
I implemented the Jack polynomials with a symbolic Jack parameter $\alpha$ in their coefficients ($\alpha=1$ for Schur polynomials, $\alpha=2$ for zonal polynomials). From my implementation (and also from the definition I think), the coefficients are fractions of polynomials in $\alpha$. But each time I compute a $J$-Jack polynomial, I observe that they actually are polynomials in $\alpha$ (I didn't check yet for the $P$-Jack polynomials and the $Q$-Jack polynomials). Is it an established fact, and are there some references about it?

Coefficients in what basis?

the combinatorial formula in Wikipedia is a polynomial in $\alpha$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_function

@CarloBeenakker Indeed, thanks! Sam Hopkins> canonical basis.

Canonical basis meaning monomial symmetric functions?

@SamHopkins No, the "ordinary" monomials, such as $x_1 x_2^2 x_3^5$.

But being a symmetric function, you can group together all the terms for the different permutations of a monomial into the monomial symmetric function, no? (Anyways sorry this discussion is probably irrelevant seeing as you got the answer you were looking for...)

@SamHopkins Thank you for this remark! This can considerably shorten the expressions of the Jack polynomials. I never had this idea.

@CarloBeenakker, re, since that seems to answer the question, maybe you can post it as an answer?

In general if you are interested in doing computer experiments with symmetric functions, I might recommend using an existing math software library, like for instance Sage: https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/sf/sfa.html

@SamHopkins I prefer my implementation :-) More seriously, this is interesting programming stuff. I didn't check yet whether I am slower or faster than Sage.

Following up on the suggestion of LSpice, to remove this from the "unanswered queue":
the combinatorial formula in Wikipedia, due to Knop and Sahi, is a polynomial in $\alpha$.

And to settle a subquestion: by definition, the '$P$-normalisation' is monic, $P_\lambda = m_\lambda + \text{lower}$, so the lower terms have coefficients that are rational functions of $\alpha$. It differs from the '$J$-normalisation by a factor that depends on $\alpha$ and remove the denominator.
